# Is there a way to prevent tab characters from being filtered with the FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW option?

Tags: php, string, validation, filter-var

Is their a regular expression or a better way to remove the same characters that the php filter_var function's FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW option does, except the tab character?

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php for the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter and FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW option.

I'm using the php filter_var function with the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter and FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH options to remove quite a few characters and 'word'-patterns, but it also removes tab characters, which I don't want removed.

If there is a good way to remove the 'low' characters other than tab, then I can remove the FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW filter option from the filter_var call and 'feed' the result to regular express substitution 'filter' or better, and 'finish' the validation.

Comment: `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` filters all byte values < 32, so `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0a-\x19]/', '', $input)` should do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with preg_replace you can remove the 'low' characters other than tab (\x09).

```
$input = "ab \x00\x01\t\r\nAcd0\x19";
$santtizeString = preg_replace('~[\x00-\x08\x0A-\x1F]~u','',$input);
```

The hexadecimal notation of $ input is

\x61\x62\x20\x00\x01\x09\x0d\x0a\x41\x63\x64\x30\x19

All characters with a code <\ x20 except tab \ x09 are removed. The result is a hex notation

\x61\x62\x20\x09\x41\x63\x64\x30

or as string "ab \tAcd0".

Comment: Thank you misorude and jspit!  I'll put these into my string validation rule.

Comment: I know that you gave me the regular expression pattern, but I thought it might be shorter and possibly clearer to invert the range to: preg_replace( '[^\t\r\n\s-~]u', '' , $string ), but this returns NULL.  Can you see what is wrong with my pattern?

Comment: Make that preg_replace( '[^\t\r\n\s!-~]u', '' , $string ), but it still returns null.  I do want this to work with UTF-8 characters.

Comment: If you also want to exclude \ r and \ n then try '~[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]~u'

Comment: Thanks again. The reason that I used the inverted list of characters was that I didn't have to specify the upper range limit as you show: \x0E-\x1F.  The other reason that I switched to [^\t\r\n\s!-~], Not ( tab, return, new line, space-like character, and not in the range exclamation through tilda ), was because I thought that it was clearer than the hex-codes, but when I switched, the u option for UTF-8 caused the regular expression to be invalid.  I also tried preg_replace( '/[^\t\r\n\s!-~]/u' ), no luck.

Comment: Just in case: I want to keep the characters I specified in the expression and replace all others with nothing.

Comment: Nevermind about using the u option, the regular expression tester I was using didn't recognise the option, but when I put the u option in my preg_replace statement that I talked about in my last comment ('/[^\t\r\n\s!-~]/u'), it worked, which is great because I can remove the redundant FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH option from the filter_var statement, because the regular expression handles the LOW and HIGH characters.